# Problems with java package names in Gradle build with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, java-package

I have a Gradle project and in it I have groovy and java classes at the same package. The build works fine but when I import the project in InteliJ 13 the IDE tells me that only in the java files I have wrong package names.

```
\src\main\groovy\com\example\boo\foo\Problem.java
```

with package

```
package com.example.boo.foo;
```

And there is no error with

```
\src\main\groovy\com\example\boo\foo\Sample.groovy
```

with package

```
package com.example.boo.foo
```

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you Java code is packaged under `java` and your groovy code is packaged under `groovy`. See example in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I know it but the compilation works fine. Only in IDEA there is a problem I looked in the code of Gradleware for example and there I see groovy and java classes at the same package.

Comment: @Xelian that's what I'm saying: you should separate them